# Differentiating Between Sockets using Select

Tags: c, sockets, select, tcp

I'm making a TCP/IP server which listens on multiple ports. I chose to use select to enable handling of multiple events.

So at the moment, i have two sockets, which are connected to two different ports (3000, 3001).

Once I'm inside the select loop, I want the server to respond differently based on the port that it is currently handling. How can I tell what socket I'm on, once inside the select?

---

I'm adding the code for my selection loop, hopefully you guys can point me in the right direction. Notice that this starts after I've added both file descriptors to the set.

```
while(1)

{

    /* Block until input arrives on one or more active sockets. */

    readfds = activefds;

    if (select (FD_SETSIZE, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0)

    {

        perror ("select");

        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

    }



    /* Service all the sockets with input pending. */

    for (i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; ++i)

    {

        if (FD_ISSET (i, &readfds))

        {

            if (i == S_time)

            {


                if ((NS = accept(S_time,NULL,NULL)) < 0)

                    ERROR("server: accept");

                FD_SET(NS, &activefds); //add the new socket desc to our active connections set

                send_time(NS);



            }

            else if (i == S_remote)// i == S_remote

            {

                fprintf(stderr,"Remote");

                int status = recieve_request(S_remote);

                /* Data arriving on an already-connected socket. */



            }

            else

            {

                break;

            }

        }

    } /* //end of for */

} /* //end of while */
```

So my two sockets are S_time and S_remote. When a client connects to the time socket, I want to send that client the current time. When a client connects to remote, I was want to do remote execution. How can i make this distinction?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Please post some code to go with this, it will help give a more accurate answer. As you havent listed your programming language its likely to lead to vague answers.

Comment: Whoops, i completely forgot the language tag, D'oh!

Comment: I edited to add my selection code, I hope you guys can help :)

Answer (score 2):

`select()` deals with file descriptors, it doesn't know anything about the port number.

You would need to keep track of this information yourself (via a map keyed by the file descriptor, for example) or simply use multiple sets of file descriptors (where each set is specific to a port) and call `select` with a zero timeout (non-blocking) on each set.

Comment: Alright, so i do have select set up that in the set there is two sockets, each has its own port associated. So then, how do i distinguish between sockets in the set?

Comment: you can't - as Brian says you have to associate each socket's file descriptor number with the desired behaviour yourself.

Comment: You can use `getsockname` and `getpeername` to extract the local and remote address and port from a socket file descriptor. But this will be **a lot** slower than keeping track of them yourself.

Comment: I completely forgot those existed. Geez the memory isn't what it used to be. Though I can't say I've ever used them, I always just kept track myself.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this explanation and sample code](http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html), seems that it answers your question. In brief, after select() returns, the corresponding descriptor is included in the corresponding set. For details follow the link.

Comment: Not only does that not address his question, it's a pretty horrid piece of code written by someone who didn't seem to really understand how to use `select()`  .. though he seemed very excited about discovering its existence.  http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html is an actual example of its use, but the OP knows this already.

Comment: @Brian ... and now let's listen to OP